# why this operation is equivalent to applying a regular dense layer in the channel domain?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In the definition of a convolutional layer, if we have I input channels, J output channels, and the filter size is chosen to be ∆ = 0, show that the operation is equivalent to applying a regular dense layer in the channel domain. What is the number of trainable parameters in this layer?